# Validação de formulário "por OnChange" com javascript

Tags: javascript, formulário, validação

Boa tarde!
Estou tentando validar um formulário por "OnChange" com javascript, o script funcionou corretamente porém está apresentando o seguinte erro:

Quando tento preencher qualquer campo do formulário sem que eu tenha preenchido os campos anteriores ele retorna para o primeiro campo.

Sou iniciante em javascript, como posso resolver isso?

O formulário com o script está aqui: http://jsbin.com/tumasupika/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Script de validação:

```
function val(){
    var campo = document.getElementsByClassName('valida');
    var alerta = document.getElementsByClassName('alerta');
    //exucuta o laço
    for(i=0;i<campo.length;i++){
        var tipo = campo.item(i).getAttribute('data-type');

        if(tipo == "text" || tipo == "number" || tipo == "select"){
            if(campo.item(i).value === "" || campo.item(i).value.length < 8){
                alerta.item(i).setAttribute('style', 'background-position:-525px');
                campo.item(i).setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #f00');
                campo.item(i).focus();
                return false;
                break;}
                alerta.item(i).removeAttribute('style');
                campo.item(i).setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#fff');
        }

        else if(tipo == "email"){
            if(campo.item(i).value.length < 10 || campo.item(i).value.indexOf('@')==-1 || campo.item(i).value.indexOf('.')==-1 || campo.item(i).value.indexOf('.com')==-1){
                alerta.item(i).setAttribute('style', 'background-position:-525px');
                campo.item(i).setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #f00');
                campo.item(i).focus();
                return false;
                break;}
                alerta.item(i).removeAttribute('style');
                campo.item(i).setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#fff');
            }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua função é de validar o `form` como um todo, não individualmente, então o correto seria você remover do `onchange` e ficar somente no `onclick`do seu botão ou então no `onsubmit` do `form`.

Outra coisa seria remover o `return false` para que ele exiba **TODOS** campos com problemas, dessa forma o `.focus()` vai ficar no último campo do **for** então se você quer que o foco seja sempre no primeiro com problema é só inverter o **for**.

```
for(i=campo.length-1;i >= 0;i--)
```

E corrigir o `if` quando for input, ficando assim

```
function val(){
    //pega os campos para digitação
    var campo = document.getElementsByClassName('valida');
    //pega os campos
    var alerta = document.getElementsByClassName('alerta');
    //exucuta o laço
    for(i=campo.length-1;i >= 0;i--){
        //pega o tipo de elemento
        var tipo = campo.item(i).getAttribute('data-type');

        //se for text...
        if(tipo == "text" || tipo == "number" || tipo == "select"){
            if(campo.item(i).value === "" || campo.item(i).value.length < 8){
                alerta.item(i).setAttribute('style', 'background-position:-525px');
                campo.item(i).setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #f00');
                campo.item(i).focus();
            } else {
                alerta.item(i).removeAttribute('style');
                campo.item(i).setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#fff');
            }
        }

        //se for email...
        else if(tipo == "email"){
            if(campo.item(i).value.length < 10 || campo.item(i).value.indexOf('@')==-1 || campo.item(i).value.indexOf('.')==-1 || campo.item(i).value.indexOf('.com')==-1){
                alerta.item(i).setAttribute('style', 'background-position:-525px');
                campo.item(i).setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #f00');
                campo.item(i).focus();
            } else {
                alerta.item(i).removeAttribute('style');
                campo.item(i).setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#fff');
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Se quiser validar individualmente, crie uma nova função, por exemplo:

```
function valIndividual(campo){
    //pega o tipo de elemento
    var tipo = campo.getAttribute('data-type');

    //se for text...
    if(tipo == "text" || tipo == "number" || tipo == "select"){
        if(campo.value === "" || campo.value.length < 8){
            campo.setAttribute('style', 'background-position:-525px');
            campo.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #f00');
            campo.focus();
        } else {
            campo.removeAttribute('style');
            campo.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#fff');
        }
    }

    //se for email...
    else if(tipo == "email"){
        if(campo.value.length < 10 || campo.value.indexOf('@')==-1 || campo.value.indexOf('.')==-1 || campo.value.indexOf('.com')==-1){
            campo.setAttribute('style', 'background-position:-525px');
            campo.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #f00');
            campo.focus();
        } else {
            campo.removeAttribute('style');
            campo.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#fff');
        }
    }       
}
```

E no `onchange` coloque `onchange=valIndividual(this)`.

Dessa forma você pode até alterar a função `val` pra algo do tipo:

```
function val(){
    //pega os campos para digitação
    var campo = document.getElementsByClassName('valida');
    //exucuta o laço
    for(i=campo.length-1;i >= 0;i--){
        valIndividual(campo.item(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Entendi @Maicon Carraro, muito obrigado, porém eu queria validar cada campo individualmente.

Comment: Pra validar cada campo individualmente, você vai precisar verificá-los pelo `id` ou `name`.

Comment: Muito obrigado @EduardoSilva

Comment: @Odair Atualizei minha resposta com a validação individual, dê uma olhada.

Comment: @MaiconCarraro Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Odair Fiz uma nova sugestão pra sua função de validar todos :)

Comment: Muito obrigado @MaiconCarraro, funcionou perfeitamente, valeu pela ajuda :)